# SQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> #### ERROR CODE
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@LNG_ID := 16; SELECT DISTINCT IF (ART_LOOKUP.ARL_KIND IN (3, 4), BRANDS.BRA_B' at line 2

And this is my PHP code w/ my queries

```
        <?php
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
//header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
$securecheck = 'live_search';
$search = $_GET['search'];
$search = str_replace(' ', '%', $search);
//$search = "%" . $search . "%";
   if($search == ''){
      die("empty query");
   }

$query = mysql_query("SET @NUMBER := '" . $search . "';
@LNG_ID := 16;

SELECT DISTINCT
    IF (ART_LOOKUP.ARL_KIND IN (3, 4), BRANDS.BRA_BRAND, SUPPLIERS.SUP_BRAND) AS BRAND,
    ART_LOOKUP.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER AS NUMBER,
    ART_LOOKUP.ARL_KIND,
    ART_LOOKUP.ARL_ART_ID,
    DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT AS ART_COMPLETE_DES_TEXT
FROM
               ART_LOOKUP
     LEFT JOIN BRANDS ON BRANDS.BRA_ID = ART_LOOKUP.ARL_BRA_ID
    INNER JOIN ARTICLES ON ARTICLES.ART_ID = ART_LOOKUP.ARL_ART_ID
    INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS ON SUPPLIERS.SUP_ID = ARTICLES.ART_SUP_ID
    INNER JOIN DESIGNATIONS ON DESIGNATIONS.DES_ID = ARTICLES.ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID
    INNER JOIN DES_TEXTS ON DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS.DES_TEX_ID
WHERE
    ART_LOOKUP.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER = @NUMBER AND
    ART_LOOKUP.ARL_KIND IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND
    DESIGNATIONS.DES_LNG_ID = @LNG_ID
GROUP BY
    BRAND,
    NUMBER
;
") or die (mysql_error());
echo $query;
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $count;
if($count > 0){
   $sql = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   do{
     echo "<div>" . $sql['ART_COMPLETE_DES_TEXT'] . "</div>";
   }while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query));
}else{
   echo "no results";
}
?>
```

Comment: Cant execute two statements in one call of `mysql_query`. Use http://www.php.net/mysqli_multi_query

Comment: Please make sure to escape `$_GET['search']` before inserting it into a DB query. And read about SQL injection.

Comment: DISTINCT and GROUP BY and no aggregating - the hat trick

Comment: i know about SQL injections, it's fixed in front-end script.

Comment: @Strawberry what you want to say?

Comment: @KirillDanshin - Strawberry is referring to your use of distinct and group by...MySQL is the only database that your statement will work on, any other database will return an error due to an invalid group by.  MySQL likes to do the wrong thing and not return an error instead...you may want to revisit what you think distinct and your group by is accomplishing here as it might not be what you think it's doing...dirty and tends to be a very common error (the hat trick as strawberry calls it) with Non-SQL programmers using MySQL.

Comment: @Twelfth thanks, I decide to delete all mysql-@vars and use php . $vars . and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to execute multiple queries. You may delete this lines:

```
SET @NUMBER := '" . $search . "';
@LNG_ID := 16;
```

and replace all `@NUMBER`  and `@LNG_ID` with corresponding PHP values, e.g.:

```
ART_LOOKUP.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER = @NUMBER AND
```

would be

```
ART_LOOKUP.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER = '".$search."' AND
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot run multiple queries using the obsolete [**mysql API**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).

- You need to use MySQLi's [`multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) for this.

Comment: ^--< ...my contribution has been recorded.