# SQL statement in PHP behaves differently than SQL statement in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have

```
$form_store_sql = "                                                                                                                    
     INSERT INTO myodyssey_myaccount (`id`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, 'email', 'unixmiah.formtest', 'woohoo');         

     SET @last_id_in_myaccount = LAST_INSERT_ID();                                                                                      

     INSERT INTO myodyssey_personal_info (`id`, `myodyssey_myaccount_id`) VALUES (NULL, @last_id_in_myaccount);                             

    SET @last_id_in_personal_info = LAST_INSERT_ID();                                                                                  

    INSERT INTO myodyssey_travel_info (`id`, `myodyssey_personal_info_id`)                                                                 
        VALUES (NULL, @last_id_in_personal_info);                                                                                                      

     SET @last_id_in_travel_info = LAST_INSERT_ID();                                                                                    

     INSERT INTO myodyssey_tour_orders (`id`, `myodyssey_travel_info_id`) VALUES (NULL, @last_id_in_travel_info);";

     if(mysql_query($form_store_sql)){
       echo "done";
     }
```

It doesn't work; it doesn't store the data. But if I take the SQL statement out of the form_store_variable and paste it into phpmyadmin's sql dialog, it behaves differently, it stores the data. I wonder what I'm doing wrong storing the SQL statement in the form_store_variable.

Comment: this is the url that builds the form:

Comment: [Déjà vue question today.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25814295/) Should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: `mysql_query` can only run one query at a time.

Comment: http://qa.odysseysafaris.com/my-odyssey-application/form-wizard/actual-form/odyssey-book-it-reservation.php

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_*()` functions do **NOT** allow multiple statements like that in a single `query` call. It's a basic defense against some forms of SQL injection attacks.

If you'd used any kind of error handling on your query call, you'd have been informed of the syntax error:

```
$result = mysql_query($form_store_sql);
if ($result === false) {
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

You will have to `query()` each of those individual statements separately.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and avoid code backfires.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query()` doesn't allow multiple queries in a single call. You need to split up `$form_store_sql` into separate strings for each query, and call `mysql_query()` separately for each of them.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO myodyssey_myaccount (`id`, `email`, `username`, `password`) 
        VALUES (NULL, 'email', 'unixmiah.formtest', 'woohoo');";
mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "SET @last_id_in_myaccount = LAST_INSERT_ID();";
mysql_query($sql);
...
```

You can also avoid doing a separate call just to set a variable to `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, by just using that function in the next insert:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO myodyssey_personal_info (`id`, `myodyssey_myaccount_id`)
        VALUES (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID());"
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. I thought whatever query you had in the sql statement from the php side would get processed in the single mysql_query function. Saved me hours worth of figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: this makes sense now. thank you. i was under the impression that it would process what you actually had on the php side; doesn't matter if it was broken up or not. it makes sense considering its a security breach.